# Interpreting the DecisionTreeRegressor score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, supervised-learning

I am trying to evaluate a relevance of features and I am using `DecisionTreeRegressor()`

The related part of the code is presented below:

```
# TODO: Make a copy of the DataFrame, using the 'drop' function to drop the given feature
new_data = data.drop(['Frozen'], axis = 1)

# TODO: Split the data into training and testing sets(0.25) using the given feature as the target
# TODO: Set a random state.

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(new_data, data['Frozen'], test_size = 0.25, random_state = 1)

# TODO: Create a decision tree regressor and fit it to the training set

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor


regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=1)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# TODO: Report the score of the prediction using the testing set

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


#score = cross_val_score(regressor, X_test, y_test)
score = regressor.score(X_test, y_test)

print score  # python 2.x
```

When I run the `print` function, it returns the given score:

> -0.649574327334

You can find the score function implementatioin and some explanation below [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/base.py#L358) and below:

> Returns the coefficient of determination **R^2** of the prediction.
>   ...
>   The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the
>           model can be arbitrarily worse).

I could not grasp the whole concept yet, so this explanation is not very helpful for me. For instance I could not understand why score could be negative and what exactly it indicates (if something is squared, I would expect it can only be positive).

---

What does this score indicates and why can it be negative?

If you know any article (for starters) it might be helpful as well!

Comment: Start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html

Comment: If you understand basics of the coefficient, then you may just read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183265/what-does-negative-r-squared-mean) and [that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative). The first article, though, is completely sufficient to comprehend the background story. Good news, it is for starters, too!

Answer (score 5):

`R^2` can be negative from its definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) if the model fits the data worse than a horizontal line. Basically

```
R^2 = 1 - SS_res/SS_tot
```

and `SS_res` and `SS_tot` are always positive. If `SS_res >> SS_tot`, you have a negative `R^2`. Look at this answer as well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative

Answer (score 0):

The article execute `cross_val_score` in which `DecisionTreeRegressor` is implemented. You may take a look at the documentation of scikitlearn [DecisionTreeRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html).
Basically, the score you see is R^2, or (1-u/v). U is the squared sum residual of your prediction, and v is the total square sum(sample sum of square).

u/v can be arbitrary large when you make really bad prediction, while it can only be as small as zero given u and v are sum of squared residual(>=0)